# I'm trying to compile the following code, but keep on getting the same error message

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PX.Data;
using System.Collections;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.CT;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.PM;

namespace PX.Objects.PM{}

public class 
ProjectBalanceEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<ProjectBalanceEntry>{}


  #region Event Handler


  public PXFilter<ProjectBalanceEntry.ProjectBalanceFilter>(Filter);
  [PXVirtualDAC]

  ProjectBalanceEntry row = e.Row as ProjectBalanceFilter;

  if (row != null)
    {
      Items.Cache.AllowInsert = row.ProjectID != null && row.AccountGroupID 
!= null;
    }

  if (Filter.Current == null)
        {
            Items.Cache = row.ProjectID != null && row.AccountGroupID != 
null;
        }

            PXSelectJoin<PMProjectStatus,
                InnerJoin<PMTask, On<PMTask.projectID, 
Equal<PMProjectStatus.projectID>>>, 
                Where<PMProjectStatus.projectID, 
Equal<Current<ProjectBalanceFilter.projectID>>, 
And<PMProjectStatus.accountGroupID, 
Equal<Current<ProjectBalanceFilter.accountGroupID>>>>,

              {
  if (project == null) project = Base.Project.Select();

  if (project != null && row != null)
 } 

             INItemSite itemsite = PXSelectJoin<INItemSite,
                InnerJoin<Location, On<Location.cSiteID, 
Equal<INItemSite.siteID>>>,
                Where<INItemSite.inventoryID, 
Equal<Required<INItemSite.inventoryID>>, And<Location.bAccountID, 
Equal<Required<Location.bAccountID>>>>>.Select(Base, row.InventoryID, 
project.CustomerID);

           if (itemsite != null)
    {
      e.NewValue = itemsite.LastCost;
    }


  e.Cancel = true;

 #endregion
```

I get the following error when validating this code:

> Validating Binary Files Validating the website C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Acumatica
>   ERP\Customization\AcumaticaPUPKT11Validation\AcumaticaPUPKT11Website
>   IIS APPPOOL.NET v4.5 Building directory
>   '\WebSiteValidationDomain\App_RuntimeCode\'.
>   \App_RuntimeCode\ProjectBalanceEntry.cs(23): error CS1518: Expected
>   class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
>   \App_RuntimeCode\ProjectBalanceEntry.cs(29): error CS1518: Expected
>   class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
>   \App_RuntimeCode\ProjectBalanceEntry.cs(23): error CS1518: Expected
>   class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct Compiler time, in seconds:
>   5.0554991 Validation failed.

Comment: It looks like there is a syntax error in the statement that begins with `PXSelectJoin`... it looks like a declaration, but one pointy bracket is missing at the end and the next line is a curly bracket indicating that there may be some lines missing. Also, curly brackets are incorrectly placed after namespace and class declarations.

Comment: I may cause some offence here but if you're looking at the code in the question and not spotting a *number* of obvious issues with the code, you need to go back to basics and *learn C#*, not expect us to assist with compiling code without you having to learn anything.

Answer (score 1):

You have `{}` in several places when I feel sure you meant `{`

```
namespace PX.Objects.PM{}

public class 
ProjectBalanceEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<ProjectBalanceEntry>{}
```

Basically something very wrong has happened to your curly braces (eg. a Find/Replace mistake). You may need to revert to an earlier version of the source code.

Also the function definitions have thr wrong syntax:

```
  public PXFilter<ProjectBalanceEntry.ProjectBalanceFilter>(Filter);
  [PXVirtualDAC]
```

probably should be

```
  [PXVirtualDAC]
  public PXFilter<ProjectBalanceEntry.ProjectBalanceFilter>(Filter)
  {
```

Comment: Even when changing the curly brackets, I stiil get the same error for lines (16) and (24).  It seems to have an issue with ProjectBalanceFilter.  It seems as if it does not find the declaration for ProjectBalanceFilter in the ProjectBalanceEntry Namespace.

Comment: It has an issue with:        public PXFilter<ProjectBalanceEntry.ProjectBalanceFilter>(Filter);
      [PXVirtualDAC]

Comment: And an issue with:        ProjectBalanceEntry row = e.Row as ProjectBalanceFilter;